# Convert Android Sensor TYPE_ORIENTATION to rotation matrix

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, rotation, orientation

Is it possible to convert the three values from an android sensor of *TYPE_ORIENTATION* to a rotation matrix?

I know this sensor is deprecated, but my device doesn't have a *ROTATION_VECTOR* nor a compass, so I'm stuck with the ORIENTATION sensor.

My goal is to animate a cube in *OpenGL* with this rotation matrix, making it look as if the phone rotates around the cube, while the cube is fixed.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: @v1sc3rr4k unfortunately not... I'm still not sure if its a generic android problem or a faulty implementation of the device we were testing it with...

Answer (score 0):

There is no API method, but it is very simple to convert Euler angles to a rotation matrix. Please see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Rotation_matrix

Comment: That's what I tried. Doesn't work unfortunately. As soon as the phone is upside down, the rotation matrix goes crazy...